# Apache ranger hive plugin for HDP cluster is not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, hdp, apache-ranger

I have a cluster HDP 3.1.5 and I have to apply ranger policies on hive but after successfully enabling hive plugin, its not getting registered in ranger --> audit --> plugin status. And all resources(database, tables) in hive became inaccessible for all users. No default policy is created after enabling hive plugin.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the service screen shot, there is no Hive service. As far as I know, before enabling the plugin, you need to create a service (repository) first.

Please follow the below steps:

1. In the second screenshot, click `+` sign for Hive.
2. You need to fill the mandatory sections; `Service Name`, `Username`, `Password`, `Jdbc.driverClassName`, `Jdbc.url` (HS2 connection url).
3. Test the connection;[image]
4. Then add the service and go to hive-plugin directory.
5. Modify `install.properties` file for hive-plugin (service name, Hive home dir etc).
6. Run `sudo ./enable-hive-plugin.sh`.
7. Restart Hive.
8. Now you should see hive-plugin in audit screen.