# Ranger Hive-Plugin don't appear in Web UI

Tags: hive-metastore, apache-ranger, hiveserver2

I have two virtual machines, first one with the Apache Ranger and LDAP running, second one with Apache Spark running. I want to use Ranger Policies to control the user's querys in Beeline, for example.

The procedure I'm doing now is running `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-thriftserver` and then creating a Resource Based Policy using the Hadoop SQL option in Ranger's web interface.
[Creating policy and sucess in connection with Hiveserver2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6s3x.jpg)
After that I run `enable-hive-plugin.sh` and I get in the console the message 'Ranger Plugin for hive has been enabled. Please restart hive to ensure that changes are effective.'
But when I return to Ranger Web UI, I can't see the plugin in Audit > Plugin Status.
[Service Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiEWr.jpg)
Here is my $SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<!-- Thriftserver -->
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
        <value>http</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
        <value>10001</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>hive.server2.webui.port</name>
    <value>10002</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
        <value>cliservice</value>
    </property>

<!-- LDAP -->
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
        <value>LDAP</value>
    </property>
                
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.url</name>
        <value>ldap://10.142.15.210:10389</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.baseDN</name>
        <value>ou=usuarios,dc=example,dc=com</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.Domain</name>
        <value></value>
    </property>
    
<!-- Ranger -->

    <property>
        <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.security.authorization.manager</name>
        <value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hive.authorizer.RangerHiveAuthorizerFactory</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

That is my ${HIVE_PLUGIN_PATH}/install.properties

```
POLICY_MGR_URL=10.142.15.210:6080 # IP FROM RANGER
REPOSITORY_NAME=hivedev
COMPONENT_INSTALL_DIR_NAME=/opt/spark
```

I tried following the answer described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478599/apache-ranger-hive-plugin-for-hdp-cluster-is-not-working) but it didn't work for me.

Some idea?

Comment: I think you need to add protocol here `POLICY_MGR_URL=10.142.15.210:6080`. it should be `POLICY_MGR_URL=http://10.142.15.210:6080`.

One more thing, have you restarted HS2 after you enabled the plugin?

Comment: I added the protocol and continue in the same situation.
About the HS2, yes,  I ran `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/stop-thriftserver.sh`
and then `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh`

Comment: Can you try to grep `RangerAdminRESTClient` in HS2 logs? Looks like there is a connection problem, and you should be seeing some logs with response details, for example `RangerAdminRESTClient: Error getting policies. ..., response={...}, serviceName=hivedev`